# UIDocumentInteractionController can only share pdf with Mail app

Tags: ios, pdf, uidocumentinteraction

When I try to open a pdf file using UIDocumentInteractionController all installed apps that can handle PDF's gets presented. If I pick the Mail app it works as intended and the file gets attached to a new mail, but every other app fails. If I try to share a document from DropBox to a PDF-viewer it works.

The code I'm using:

```
- (void)presentOptionsForFilename:(NSString *)path {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    if (url) {
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: url];
        if (self.documentInteractionController != nil) {
            self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
            [self.documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero
                                                                    inView:self.view
                                                                  animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I pick an app that is not Mail I get these entries in the device console. I don't they are related to the issue as they also get there when I open a pdf from DropBox where it works.

```
Sep  3 12:37:13 <devicename>-iPad com.apple.mdt[262] <Notice>: Copy /var/mobile/Applications/80BC2CCF-E49A-4800-8005-30DD304701CF/tmp/DBExportDir/Getting Started.pdf -> /private/var/mobile/Applications/3374FC4A-D57F-476E-ABC9-94A2484343D6/Documents/Inbox
Sep  3 12:37:14 <devicename>-iPad wirelessproxd[36] <Notice>: (Note ) stopped advertising for sharingd
Sep  3 12:37:14 <devicename>-iPad wirelessproxd[36] <Notice>: (Error) error event: (<OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x192c3bdc8> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x192c3c0d0> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that path was a symbolic link to another file. After changing it to a hard link it worked.